# How to convert list which contains a single string with multiple entries inside of string. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say you have a list, which contains a single string as:

```
listExample = ['cat, dog, mouse, elephant']
```

So printing this list return the values as a single string:

```
>>>'cat, dog, mouse, elephant'
```

How do you get this string to the point where you can get the entries as multiple strings, such as:

```
>>>print(anotherList)
>>>['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> listExample = ['cat, dog, mouse, elephant']
>>> listExample[0].split(', ')
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the split method.
So do

```
'cat, dog, mouse, elephant'.split(', ')
```

this will give you

```
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant']
```

The `', '` means the string should be split every time there is a comma and then a space.

The list is not needed, but if you absolutely have to use the list then do

```
listExample[0].split(', ')
```

to get the string out of the list and then split it.

For more information see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)